# Can I connect our external FTTP optical fibre to the WAN port on our router?

Tags: fiber, optical-media

We have BT Fibre to the Premises, FTTP, and a Unifi Dream Machine Pro, UDMP. Currently, the BT connection terminates at a Nokia ONT, which hands off an RJ45 which is connected to the UDMP with a cat6a patch cable. As far as I can tell, the ONT is just like any other media converter, so can I cut out the middle man and connect the BT optical fibre directly to an SFP port on the UDMP? This would ensure that we have fibre directly into the network.

I know I could just try it, however we do not have any SFP modules spare and don't want to buy one unnecessarily. I have also asked BT, but their representative did not know what SFP was.

Comment: I'll need to dig a little for a fuller answer but if memory serves - there's some config on the ont/onr/cpe side with the isp and the transceiver you would need would be a GPON one - which seems uncommon in the wild

Comment: Update for anyone who is interested - I ultimately decided against FTTD as the difference is arguably minimal over cat6a. Still an interesting question though for anyone who is interested in FTTD.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to take into account.

*Firstly* Most ISP support folks are not actually going to know much more than "we give you a box, we plug it in, and it works" - There's probably a few ISPs that do better than the basics, but mine didn't even know how to configure IPv6 when asked.

I suspect that taking that into account, setting up SFP is going to be *interesting* and require a few things the average person can't get. The average FTTP connection uses GPON - and you *might* be able to get a GPON transceiver pretty easily - Just make sure you get one meant for ONTs/ONUs not OLTs.

On the other hand, I can't find any information for the *software*/*authentication* side of things. Looking at the guide for one of my local ISPs, and the ubiquitous Huawei ONRs that many of them use suggests there's some form of authentication

[image]

Its not clear how you'd set that ID in the dream machine, or how you'd get it from an ISP

I'd say with the *right* ISP it might be doable, but getting the information you need to set it up with most is going to be tricky

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting read, more to the point it looks like what you suggest/requested info about is feasible.

https://www.ispreview.co.uk/talk/threads/replace-isp-ont-onu-with-gpon-fibre-transceiver.40637/post-328141

"I just had to copy the LOID for the ONT itself and username and password for the PPPoE connection."

I am facing a similar question which I require definitive solution to. However, it seems that for the compatibility side of things there will be some trial and error involved regarding compatible SFP+ modules/transceivers.

IDK what other additional information can be gleaned from chatter between router and ONT when establishing PPPoE session / DROP I'm thinking maybe Wireshark to try and grasp the problem better..

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It indicates the requirements, as per OP, as in the prerequisites needed to accomplish goal PPPoE Login Creds + Logical identifier (LOID) authentication. So, what is refenced in the forum post describes a method to achieve what's required.